# How can I tell whether a joystick axis / mouse movement is triggered / released?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

Basically, I need an extension of Unity's built-in GetButtonDown() and GetButtonUp() functions which not only work for buttons but also joystick axis and mouse movement.
To be more specific:
Extended GetButtonDown() should also return true when:
1. Joystick starts moving.
2. Mouse starts moving.
Extended GetButtonUp() should also return true when:
1. Joystick starts to return to origin.
2. Mouse stops moving.

How should I write these two functions?

Answer (score 0):

**Unity's Input system has what is called an 'Axis'. You can use this as the joystick behaviour you mentioned. It goes between -1, 0 and 1, 0 being the default value and the min and max values being -1 and 1 respectively.**

To see the Input Manager where you can inspect the axes and how they behave, go to:

Edit->Project Settings->Input.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html

Example usage of the axis system:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
public float speed = 10.0F;
public float rotationSpeed = 100.0F;
void Update() {
    float translation = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
    float rotation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
    translation *= Time.deltaTime;
    rotation *= Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Translate(0, 0, translation);
    transform.Rotate(0, rotation, 0);
}
}
```

Bonus info:

There is also GetAxisRaw, which only returns -1, 0 and 1 with no values in between.